# why does my app break when i try to get images from external storage with async task in android

Tags: java, android

I want to get photos from external storage and app breaks when refresh is done very fastly works fine with slow refreshing.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()` is shown

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        binding.refreshView.setRefreshing(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
            File file = allFiles[i];

            if (Uri.fromFile(file).toString().endsWith(".jpeg") || Uri.fromFile(file).toString().endsWith(".gif")
                    || Uri.fromFile(file).toString().endsWith(".jpg") || Uri.fromFile(file).toString().endsWith(".png")) {
                satusModal  modal = new satusModal(file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), "whats" + i, Uri.fromFile(file));
                list.add(modal);
            }
            publishProgress();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        //
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(list.size()>=1) {

            adapter = new WhatsAppAdapter(list,getContext());
            binding.recyclerViewFromImagesFragment.setAdapter(adapter);}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        super.onPostExecute(unused);

        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(list.size()>=1) {


            adapter = new WhatsAppAdapter(list,getContext());
            binding.recyclerViewFromImagesFragment.setAdapter(adapter);}
        else binding.warningNoStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}.execute();
```

[Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1r7.png)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace as well? However it also possible that the crash is due to `binding.refreshView.setRefreshing(false);` in `doInBackground`. Move that to `onPreExecute()` maybe.

Comment: i did it. Please take a look

Comment: 1. I still don't see the stacktrace. 2. Did you try moving the said line from `doInBackground` to `onPreExecute`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1r7.png

Comment: yes i moved the said line

Comment: Your `list` variable is `null`. Did you initialise it like `ArrayList<satusModal> list = new ArrayList()`?

Comment: yes. how can i send you full code

Comment: Do not create a new adapter for every file added to the list. Makes no sense to do that in onProgressUpdate. Instead you should do that once in onPostExecute.

Comment: @blackapps i want to show the image same time it is loaded for better UI.

Comment: You are on the wrong way. Design your app better. Images should be loaded lazy anyway so what you try to do makes no sense.

Comment: how would i do that